# How to reference a DAG's execution date inside of a `KubernetesPodOperator`?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I am writing an Airflow DAG to pull data from an API and store it in a database I own. Following best practices outlined in [We're All Using Airflow Wrong](https://medium.com/bluecore-engineering/were-all-using-airflow-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it-a56f14cb0753), I'm writing the DAG as a sequence of `KubernetesPodOperator`s that run pretty simple Python functions as the entry point to the Docker image.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that this DAG should only pull data for the `execution_date`.

If I was using a `PythonOperator` ([doc](http://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html)), I could use the `provide_context` argument to make the execution date available to the function. But judging from [the KubernetesPodOperator's documentation](http://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator/index.html), it seems that the Kubernetes operator has no argument that does what `provide_context` does.

My best guess is that you could use the `arguments` command to pass in a date range, and since it's templated, you can reference it like this:

```py
my_pod_operator = KubernetesPodOperator(
    # ... other args here
    arguments=['python', 'my_script.py', '{{ ds }}'],
    # arguments continue
)
```

And then you'd get the start date like you'd get any other argument provided to a Python file run as a script, by using `sys.argv`.

Is this the right way of doing it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your question asks if that is the "right" way, but doesn't specify if you have some obstacle to doing it that way. Does it work? Does your script choke if provided an extra date? Is there some reason you don't want to do what you have described? Also, be forewarned there is an explicit close vote for opinion based questions, so yours currently is at risk of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way of doing it.

Each Operator would have `template_fields`. All the parameters listed in `template_fields` can render Jinja2 templates and Airflow Macros.

For KubernetesPodOperator, if you check [docs](http://airflow.apache.org/1.10.3/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator.template_fields), you would find:

```
template_fields = ['cmds', 'arguments', 'env_vars', 'config_file']
```

which means you can pass `'{{ ds }}'`to any of the four params listed above.

Comment: e.g. `arguments=['{{ ds }}']` - see Template Configuration https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator